# New environment using the `multicols` environment

Tags: multicol, technical-environment

In the following code, I want to define a customized version of the environment `multicols`. The output is good but the compilation sends the following message : `\begin{submulticols} on input line 95 ended by \end{multicols}`. What am  I doing wrong ?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \newlength{\mycolumnsep}
    \newlength{\mycolumnseprule}

    \setlength{\mycolumnsep}{1cm}
    \setlength{\mycolumnseprule}{0.2pt}


    \newlength{\mysubcolumnsep}
    \newlength{\mysubcolumnseprule}

    \setlength{\mysubcolumnsep}{0.5cm}
    \setlength{\mysubcolumnseprule}{0pt}


    \setlength{\columnsep}{\mycolumnsep}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{\mycolumnseprule}


    \newenvironment{submulticols}[1]{%
        \setlength{\columnsep}{\mysubcolumnsep}
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{\mysubcolumnseprule}
        \begingroup
        \multicols{#1}
    }{%
        \endmulticols
        \endgroup
        %\setlength{\columnsep}{\mycolumnsep}
        %\setlength{\columnseprule}{\mycolumnseprule}
    }


\begin{document}

\section{Exemple 1}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

    \begin{submulticols}{2}
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
    \end{submulticols}


    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{multicols}


\section{Exemple 2}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla


    \begin{submulticols}{4}
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
        ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok 
    \end{submulticols}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\begin{multicols}` and `\end{multicols}`, because the environment relies on seeing `\end`.

You need no `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, because an environment already forms a group.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newlength{\mycolumnsep}
\newlength{\mycolumnseprule}
\setlength{\mycolumnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\mycolumnseprule}{0.2pt}

\newlength{\mysubcolumnsep}
\newlength{\mysubcolumnseprule}
\setlength{\mysubcolumnsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\mysubcolumnseprule}{0pt}

\setlength{\columnsep}{\mycolumnsep}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{\mycolumnseprule}


\newenvironment{submulticols}[1]{%
  \setlength{\columnsep}{\mysubcolumnsep}%
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{\mysubcolumnseprule}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
}{%
  \end{multicols}
}


\begin{document}

\section{Exemple 1}

\begin{multicols}{2}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\begin{submulticols}{2}
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
\end{submulticols}


bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{multicols}


\section{Exemple 2}

\begin{multicols}{2}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla


\begin{submulticols}{4}
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok 
\end{submulticols}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Give me a staircase, I would climb the mountain with my bare hands. I need to learn more about `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`